# solr - Stop facet calculation by sending a request to solr

Tags: solr, facet, solrcloud, faceted-search, solr6

I have an `index` with 1M docs and 50 facets. Out of the 50 facets I want solr to stop calculating 1 `facet` (i.e. `brand_facet`) **only sometimes** when issued a search request using `/search` handler. It is a multivalue field. How can I achieve it by sending a request to solr OR is there anyother way to achieve it? I have been searching for a while now but cant seem to find any helpful post about it.

Comment: Exactly what is your problem? Does the facet calculation take too much time? Why? Why are you requesting the facet in that case?

Comment: yes the facet calculation takes a lot of time as it has a lot of values. It is a high cardinality facet. I am using JSON facets. @MatsLindh